# Actor model: how to reach data integrity in this specific situation?

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, distributed-computing, actor, orleans

I'm new to actor model and Orleans, so any suggestions on good practices to solve the following task is very appreciated:

we have [service1] that runs some logic and store some results in relational database (legacy thing). Now somewhere in the middle we want to call Orleans actor [Actor1] which holds a list of numbers, to get the next available number. The goal of the [Actor1] is to feed the numbers sequentially and consistently, so no skip over, no duplication is allowed, so it's sort of single-threaded stack. Single-threaded not only per process, but throughout the cluster of services, exactly what we need.

```
[service1] -> [Actor1]
```

Now the only problem I see here is that [service1] can fail with exception after it takes the next number, but before it stores results in database. Number is taken from the single-threaded stack, but it's lost as calling application did not manage to store results based on the fed number in database. In other words, I do not want the actor to feed next number, unless it ensures the last fed one is in good use, and only calling application knows if it is.

How would you suggest to handle these situations? Can I somehow keep Orleans actor's job open unless calling service (or another actor) commits it to database?

Comment: actors are good finite state machines, you can make its state pending after fetching the value and confirming it after service1's job is done (another call). But keep in mind that you'll need to handle communication issues

Comment: @Fabio, could you please clarify how can I make actor's state 'pending'? Maybe you can reference some existing projects or relevant articles? Thanks!

Comment: I mean having not only the sequence number as a state in the actor, but also a boolean saying if the last operation has completed, so you can generate a new number.

Comment: but then I'll have to manually block all subsequent calls inside the grain unless the boolean flag lets go further, and put them into wait state manually vs. relying on actor model framework on that. It might work, but I thought may be there are some nicer solutions of the problem

Comment: And what should happen, when the actor fails after receiving the confirmation that this number is used and can't persist it's state? Will it serve this number again? Will the actor confirm the confirmation? Or wait for the confirmation of the confirmation of the confirmation? This is a Byzantine problem, so there is no easy solution.

Comment: chances for actor to fail storing its state are significantly lower than chances calling legacy application fails to successfully handle the number, due to nature of nature of the legacy app. We can disregard first one and assume some error occur over time, but can't disregard second, the error would be too high

Answer (score 1):

This is a Byzantine problem, so there is no easy solution: there will be "holes" in the number sequence or you will use the same number twice.

I would prefer to get holes and fill them with dummy data later if this is necessary (eg. if this is a billing system, end of month enter a cancelled empty bill for each bill number that is a "hole").

Even in SQL, an Insert and a Rollback will let the sequence incremented in an auto-increment primary-key ID column, so there can be holes after a failure.